# What is the difference between pointer to function and pointer to WINAPI function?

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers

I came accross a code snippet which detects whether app is running in x32 emulated environment on x64 PC  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(VS.85).aspx)

Generally I understand that code but there is one thing I don't get:

1) typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) (HANDLE, PBOOL);

Why does WINAPI have to be there? Why is it so important to know that pointer doesn't point to my-defined function but to WINAPI one? Would these 2 pointers be different? (in way of size, place they are created etc.)

Thanks,

Kra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WINAPI expands to __stdcall (in most cases -- you shouldn't rely on that calling convention specifically), which is a different calling convention than the default, __cdecl. The difference is that in __stdcall, the function called cleans the stack, while in __cdecl, the caller cleans the stack. __stdcall does not support varadic (Variable argument length) functions like __cdecl does, but __stdcall can be faster and reduce code size in some cases.

Comment: So, in nutshell, WINAPI says compiler to not generate code to clean up the mess on the stack after the function has finished?

Comment: @Kra: For the most part, yes. I'm not sure how that translates into x86_64, but that's definitely the case with x86.

Comment: Cool, it makes sense then, that compiler does not moan when WINAPI is removed and that app crashes with info that value of ESP wasnt properly saved accross function call. Thank you for sharing your knowledge :)

Comment: @Kra: For future diagnosis, all I did was right click WINAPI in my IDE to see what it was `#define` d as. Then I googled __stdcall. Using the header files is a good way to figure out what things are doing :)

Answer (score 1):

`WINAPI` is a *macro* that normally contains implementation-specific declaration details related to WinAPI functions. Like a calling convention. The above pointer *can* point to *any* function as long as it follows the same calling convention as WinAPI functions do.

The fact that this macro is spelled as `WINAPI` has no significance whatsoever. It could have been spelled `A`, `HELLO_WORLD` or anything else. The whole and only point of that `WINAPI` macro is to provide a single place where all these WinAPI-specific conventions are described, so that in case something changes you'd only have to modify it in one place.

It could easily be a macro that resolves to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the previous posts.
BTW I really don't understand why `__cdecl` is still considered the "default" calling convention for C/C++.

Obviously using `__cdecl` results in a slightly bigger code than `__stdcall`, since the function is written once and usually called from within several code pieces. Yes, `__cdecl` is more flexible since it allows variable arguments length. But this shoule be used IMHO only for the appropriate functions marked with `...`.

For instance for member functions call (aka `thiscall`) Msvc does exactly this: uses `__stdcall`-like calling convention unless the function accepts variable arguments.
(In addition the `this` is passed via `ECX` register).

Comment: @valdo: You'll have to take that up with your compiler vendor. C++ does not say jack about calling conventions other than that `extern "C"` is allowed to change the calling convention.